# Is Cracked Tusk Keep supposed to be empty?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have finished all of the main quests except the Thieves guild ones(Oh and I haven’t done the civil war quest either) including all the DLC’s so have been playing a long, long time and through all that I have never seen any NPC in Cracked Tusk Keep since I first visited. The interior seem to be re-spawning i.e. new health potions on the table etc. but never an NPC. It’s been so long I can’t remember which faction actually occupied it in the first place.
Its tucked there in the corner of the map, which I don’t pass often, but it’s always empty. It looks a prime location for any bandit chief but no one has taken it up.

Is it supposed to be empty, is it part of a quest line I have missed or even a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [UESP Wiki says](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Cracked_Tusk_Keep): "Cracked Tusk Keep - Respawn Time: Never (storage is safe)"

It also says:

> Bugs - If the Amulet of the Moon quest directs you here, check to see
>   if you have already visited this location. This location does not
>   respawn, so if you have been here before, the Moon Amulet cannot spawn
>   here and you cannot complete the quest.  You will need to reload a
>   previous save to get a different location from Kharjo.

Answer (score 3):

[Cracked Tusk Keep](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Cracked_Tusk_Keep) is a part of the [quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pieces_of_the_Past) to reforge the [Mehrunes' Razor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mehrunes%27_Razor). It can also be a target of several radiant quests.

Comment: Silus Vesuius If he's the guy in his own place with the red banners outside, he got killed while re-forging the Mehrunes' Razor. I have the Razor in my home in Solitude on display, but I don’t remember going to Cracked Tusk Keep during that quest.

Comment: Well, you have.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cracked Tusk](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Cracked_Tusk_Keep) is a location you must enter during the [Pieces of the Past](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Pieces_of_the_Past) quest.

This is a [Daedric](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Daedric_Artifacts_%28Skyrim%29) quest you get from [Silus Vesuius](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Silus_Vesuius) in [Dawnstar](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dawnstar). I think that once you've activated that quest and head for the Cracked Tusk, enemies will spawn there.